# How to run process through first row only in R?

Tags: r, data.table, multiple-columns

I have a line of code that includes data.table package which allows me to identify all the rows and look if the cell contains the word "Margin".

```
Census_Bureau_Data<-Filter(function(Census_Bureau_Data) !any(Census_Bureau_Data %like% "Margin"), Census_Bureau_Data)
```

The code works perfectly and allows me to remove the columns that contain one row with the word Margin. Though I got result I wanted, I only want my script to limit the process to the first row. This is in case in the future the word Margin happens to appear somewhere outside of the first row and i wouldn't necessarily want my whole column deleted because of that. I only care about the first column.

```
Census_Bureau_Data<-Filter(function(Census_Bureau_Data) !any(Census_Bureau_Data[1,] %like% "Margin"), Census_Bureau_Data)
```

so i tried this instead. Note the bracket i added. I thought this would be enough. This should be simple enough. Where can I maintain the same string but just have it run through the first row?

```
[1,]
```

Comment: Change `!any(Census_Bureau_Data %like% "Margin")` to `!any(Census_Bureau_Data[1, ] %like% "Margin")` (Though at that point you don't really need the `any()` anymore, `!(Census_Bureau_Data[1, ] %like% "Margin")` should work too.)

Comment: so your first option I already did. I get <Error in Census_Bureau_Data[1, ] : incorrect number of dimensions >. No difference i remove any. @Gregor.Thomas

Comment: I think you get the `incorrect number of dimensions` error because inside the anon-func, `Census_Bureau_Data` is a *vector*, not a frame or anything complex enough to be multi-dimensional. (The fact that it is named the same as the whole table externally is certainly cause for confusion.)

Comment: @r2evans i want to delete the columns based on the values of the first row. My original script does that but it takes all the rows instead of just the first row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I found this to work.

```
Census_Bureau_Data<-Filter(function(Census_Bureau_Data) !(Census_Bureau_Data[[1]]  %like% "Margin"), Census_Bureau_Data)
```

i removed "any" as the comments suggested and added a double bracket [[1]]. I also ran tests. So i added the word "margin" in column 5 and row 5.

When i ran my original the cell that included the word margin in the 5th row and column had their column deleted. When i ran the code i have here the script applied only to Row 1 and it kept the column I had.

Answer (score 3):

Two comments:

1. I think it's a little confusing (though not an error) to have the anonymous function's argument named the same as the external object itself, so for brevity I'll use `function(xyz) ...` here.
2. Realize that in that function, `xyz` is a *vector* of data, not a frame of data, so `[,1]` or `[1,]` are meaningless.
3. Since you're only looking at the first row's worth of values, you don't need `any`, just `[1]`.

I think this is what you need:

```r
Filter(
  function(xyz) !(xyz[1] %like% "Margin"),
  Census_Bureau_Data
)
```

However, while the use of `Filter` is not wrong, I think this can be simplified a little:

```r
# data.table
Census_Bureau_Data[, !Census_Bureau_Data[1,,drop=TRUE] %like% "Margin", with = FALSE ]

# data.frame or tbl_df
Census_Bureau_Data[, !Census_Bureau_Data[1,,drop=TRUE] %like% "Margin" ]
```

Comment: the script dropped my rows instead of columns.

Comment: Oops, corrected, two ways: (1) comma in the wrong place (insert *Office Space* joke here); (2) was missing `with=FALSE`. Both corrections in the second code block. (The first, `Filter`, still works for me.)

Comment: Error in `[.data.frame`(Census_Bureau_Data, , !Census_Bureau_Data[1, ,  : 
  unused argument (with = FALSE)

Comment: That suggests that this is not a `data.table`. Would you care to [edit] your question and provide a reproducible dataset? Something like `dput(head(Census_Bureau_Data))` would be really good and remove any/all ambiguity on this.

Comment: If your data is not `data.table`, remove `with=FALSE` and it should still work. The only time it doesn't is if you have `factor`s.